# What causes this emulator error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator

ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in ''

Below are the configuration setting for the emulator

AVD Name: Nexus 5 API 23
RAM: 1536
VM Heap: 1GB
Internal Storage: 800MB
Camera: None
Graphics: Auto

Comment: Please change your emulator configuration **Uncheck the snapshot option then start the emulator**

Comment: Where can I find the snapshot option in Android Studio?

Comment: when you create new AVD, you reach to last screen then you can show that option.you can see here http://imgur.com/a/A9z4e when you observe in Emulator Performance

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the Error language that your trying to run a camera app or a app that needs the camera, and your emulator is setting your camera to None. I would try something like "Adding a new emulator and adding a camera to it".

Comment: Nothing in my app needs the camera, infact here is all the code in my MainActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    
        Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true)
                .build();

    }